# Is it possible to stick a <div> container and its content together with the background-image?

Tags: css, image

I try to put a  container on top of a background image. The content of this container will be images. Unfortunately I can't get the container stick to to background-image if I resize the browser window.

Is there  way that a container always stays at the same place but also scales together with the background-image? Let's say the background-image is 1000x1000px and the container on top is 500x500. On a smaller browser the images scales down to lets say 500x500px. Now the container and its content should also scale down 50% but should stay at the same place.

This is what I have so far (it's just an example):

```css
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; font-family: Arial, sans-sarif; font-size: 10px;  }

#background_image { 
background-image: url("http://ws2-media1.tchibo-content.de/newmedia/art_img/MAIN_ALT_3-IMPORTED/4113906f0b0eab32/regal-weiss.jpg"); 
max-width: 55.3em; 
width: 100%;
max-height: 47.1em;
height: 100%;
background-size:contain; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; } 

#container { background-color: #FF0004;  max-width: 5em; width: 100%; max-height: 5em; height: 100%; position: relative; left: 40%; top: 55%; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>

<style>



</style>

</head>

<body>

<section id="background_image"> 

<div id="container"></div>

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: An actual background image...that's pretty hard...but an inline image...that's easier. http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to try it but I guess that will work for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is media queries

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #background_image{
   }

  #container {

    }
}
```

depending on what size of the screen is u need to position the #container and give the right width of the  #background_image

This is where i learn
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.